# Proving this logical equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

**Proving the following logical equivalence:**

**E**:

[image]

*My method:*

**Let A be:**

[image]

**Let B be:**

[image]

=> E is True if

[image]

is True because:

[image]

The problem is I can't simplify the expression below to T. Not sure if I did something wrong or this can't be proved by this method.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint: when you are trying to simplify something of the form $A \land B$, you can assume $A$ when you are simplifying $B$ (because if $A$ were false $A \land B$ would be false regardless of what $B$ is). So you can exclude the cases in the truth table where $p \land \lnot q$ is false.

Comment: You're dealing with an instance of the general fact that $a\land(a\lor b)$ is equivalent to $a$ (with $a$ being $p\land\neg q$ and $b$ being $q\land\neg r$ in your particular case). It may be easier to prove the general fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B := p\wedge\neg q$, $C:=q\wedge\neg r$, and $A:=B\wedge(B\vee C)$ .

You wish to show that when $B$ is valued true, that $A$ must be too, and when $B$ is valued false, $A$ must be also.   That is $A\iff B$.

Now $B$ is true exactly when we value $p$ true and $q$ false.   $C$ is true exactly when we value $q$ true and $r$ false; so $C$ and $B$ cannot both be true under the same valuation.

Complete the restricted table $\begin{array}{c:c|c} B & C & A:B\wedge (B\vee C)\\\hline T & F & \\ F & T & \\ F & F & \end{array}$

Comment: Thank you. I got it. It's so simple. I thought I need to prove the (BVC) to be true.

Comment: Actually, when we write it like this B∧(B∨C), We can conclude that it equal to B because of Absorption Laws.

Comment: Yeap. Introducing Absorption Laws and such should be the next step in the course, if they haven't been already.